# How to get WPF DataGrid to not display a blank row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to set a DataGrid's ItemSource equal to a list, and then display the content of that list.

My XAML looks like

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridDemo"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="aGrid" ItemsSource= "{Binding actorList}" />

</Grid>
</Window>
```

My MainWindow code looks like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using A1;
namespace DataGridDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<Actor> actorList = new List<Actor>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            Actor a = new Actor("Jaba",32);
            Actor b = new Actor("Java", 46);
            Actor c = new Actor("Jaga", 23);
            actorList.Add(a);
            actorList.Add(b);
            actorList.Add(c);
            InitializeComponent();
            aGrid.ItemsSource = actorList;


    }
}
}
```

and if it matter my actor class looks like

```
  namespace A1
{
 public class Actor
{
    Random rand { get; set; }
    String name { get; set; }
    int age { get; set; }


    public Actor()
    {
        name = "Blank Blankerson";
        age = rand.Next(80) + 6;
    }
    public Actor(String n)
    {
        name = n;
        age = rand.Next(80) + 6;
    }
    public Actor(String n, int a)
    {
        age = a;
        name = n;
    }

    public override String ToString()
    {
        return name + "," + age.ToString();
    }
}
```

Every time the code runs, it generates 3 blank rows like so[image]

Every tutorial on the internet I can find says you just set dataGrid.ItemSource = List. This has only generated the following error in both my attempts. It's frustrating because I am following the tutorials and this is still my result.

So, how do I make a WPF DataGrid display a List?

Comment: How many rows do you expect to see?  Note that the `DataGrid` has the ability to show a few rows for adding, searching, etc.  Perhaps this is what you are seeing.

Comment: I think your DataGrid code is not enough. Did you try AutoGenerateColumns="True"?

Comment: I have tried setting AutoGenerateColumns to true, I am also adding 3 elements and seeing 3 empty rows.

Comment: Your data members should be public in Actor class.

Comment: You don't want rand as a Property of your class. It just needs to be a private field. Random rand = new Random()

Comment: Why can't you remove Itemsource from  <DataGrid x:Name="aGrid" ItemsSource= "{Binding actorList}" /> and just use   aGrid.ItemsSource = actorList; and also look for any error in Output window in Visual studio

Answer (score 1):

DataGrid requires that the get and set methods be public. I changed this accordingly. It now displays.

Comment: I suggest you put the sample in your answer for changes that you made in your code.

Comment: More generally, WPF Bindings require public properties. It's not just the DataGrid

Answer (score 0):

You need to set **`AutoGenerateColumns="True"`** unless if you are defining your own template  for the columns

```
<DataGrid x:Name="aGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource= "{Binding actorList}" />
```

**EDIT**

You should set the datacontext for the window

```
  InitializeComponent();
  DataContext = this;
  aGrid.ItemsSource = actorList;
```

- actorList needs to be a property in your datacontext, i.e. the mainwindow
- Additionally you should think about implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in your model